# Why my hyperparameters code is not working?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, hyperparameters

I'm trying to improve my linear regression using hyperparameters calculations and my code is not working, the error code write need to specify CV  inside and the inside parameters can't be find in sckit import.

I try to change the code without success.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import random 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3456) 

#nr.seed(3456)

## Define the dictionary for the grid search and the model object to search 

param_grid = {"M": [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0,10.0]}

## Define the linear regression model

#lin_mod = linear_model.LogisticRegression(class_weight = {0:0.45, 1:0.55}) 
lin_mod = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)

## Perform the grid search over the parameters

clf = ms.GridSearchCV(estimator = lin_mod, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 3, 

scoring = 'roc_auc', return_train_score = True)

 # Use the inside folds

## Fit the cross validated grid search over the data 

clf.fit(train_X, train_y)

## And print the best parameter value

clf.best_estimator_.M
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear; what exactly do you mean "*not working*"? Please update your post with the full error message

Answer (score 0):

These three line changes,to apply to your code,  may get you further

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


lin_mod = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = lin_mod, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 3,
    scoring = 'roc_auc', return_train_score = True)
```